# A way to universally "Show in Directory" using default file manager

Tags: command-line, files, utilities

I need to programatically "Show in Directory" a file (or another directory, but that's less important).

I intend to copy the feature from browsers that allows the user to click a button to open the file manager in the Downloads directory, but with the downloaded file selected in the view.

I have looked at `xdg-open` but it doesn't seem to be able to do this (in my opinion, a crucial design flaw, since it aims for compatibility).

My current approach for Windows and Macintosh looks like this.

```py
def show_file(path):
    if sys.platform == "darwin":
        subprocess.check_call(["open", "--reveal", path])
    elif sys.platform == "linux":
        pass
    elif sys.platform == "win32":
        subprocess.check_call(["explorer", "/select", path])
```

Is there no other alternative to manually creating a table of all of the commands for the most popular Linux file managers?

I can use `nautilus --select [path]`, but what about others?

How does Chromium do it? And where is that code?

Comment: How does Chromium do it? [`chromium/src/chrome/browser/platform_util_linux.cc`](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/platform_util_linux.cc?l=126)

Comment: @muru Well, damn. That means that Google has the same problem.

Comment: @l0b0 You didn't understand the question.

Comment: can you define "Show in Directory"?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, honestly, I don't think I should have to, I think you know what I'm talking about and you're just challenging the question. But regardless, I intend to copy the feature from browsers that allows the user to click a button to open the file manager in the Downloads directory, but with the downloaded file selected in the view.

Comment: No I am not messing with you. If I knew then I would have just improved your question. However you are correct, you don't have to, but you may find that you get better answers if you explain in the question, not everyone reads the comment.